# CSS min-height + increment size

Tags: css

I have an element `min-height: 200px;`. Is it possible to set increment size to `50px` (or any other size), ie. if content grows larger than `200px`, `205` becomes `250`; `290` becomes `300` and so on.

I know how to achieve this using JS. I am not asking for JS solution. I am interested if there is CSS solution.

Comment: off my head i'll pull a javascript solution.

Comment: @BoltClock: Enjoying the `css4` tag?

Comment: Never heard of this functionality in any of the CSS specs. It may well have to be a JS solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of using css3 cool feature of transition but it will not do 100% works but at least couple of transitions are possible on different stages.

http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/transition-active/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible without using some programming language. If you are trying to resize a div without dynamic control like js or jquery, how u can control it by css? By percent is easy, but I think is not your case.